# Error in assign - invalid first argument

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new data frame column and assign values to it within a for-loop.

Specifically, I have a list of data frame names and I am looping over this list one by one. For each name I want to create a column `$location` for that data frame and I want to assign it a value.  For simplicity sake, let's say I want to assign it `NA`.  The code below explains what I'm trying to do.  However, when I run it, I receive the error `Error in assign(get(name)$location, NA) : invalid first argument`

```
names<-c("europe", "africa", "asia")
# where each of the strings in `names` is the name of an existing data frame object
# for sake of example, code is provided below to create example data frame objects

x <- c(2,6,7)
y <- c(40, 42, 14)
europe <- data.frame(x,y)
africa <- data.frame(x,y)
asia <- data.frame(x,y)

for (name in names) {
  assign(get(name)$location, NA)
}
```

My goal is to get a new column called location in each of my data frames. I have no idea how to correct this or why it is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try your code I get `Error in get(name) : object 'europe' not found`
So I cna't add a column of something that it is not even an object.
I would try something like that

```
for (k in length(names)) {
  location <- c(data1, data2)
  assign(names[k], location)
}
```

And then convert to the format you would like, so `as.data.frame` would work after that

**EDIT**: Playing a little bit around (and thinking) it it seems that you cannot change the column values like this. From the help page `Assign a value to a name in an environment.` and that is not what you are trying to achieve, to change the value of a column I would get `rbind` this column to the data or `subs`.

Comment: The data frames already have value in my workspace…I left the names in to show what I am trying to do. I will edit my question to add code to create a europe data frame.

Answer (score -2):

```
for (k in names) {
    assign(names[k], cbind(names[k], data.frame(location = NA)))
}
```

Comment: please provide some more information to your code that will help to SO Users.