# Modifying an object referenced by "get()" in R

Tags: r, dataframe, get, assign, names

Apologies if this has been asked before. It's at the limit of my understanding of R, so I'm not even sure of the correct language in which to couch the query (hence, my inability to identify duplicate questions).

In my environment, I have an unknown number of objects (dataframes), each of which has an unknown number of columns that have meaningful names but with nonsense endings, which make it hard to reference them.  The meaningful parts of the column names are usually followed by a double period and some further text.  I want to automate finding and removing the meaningless suffixes.  All the objects I want to modify have ".dat" in their names.  Here's my attempt at an example:

```
# create some objects in my environment
a <- "a string, not of interest to me"
b.dat <- data.frame(col1 = 1:2, col2..gibberish = 3:4)
c.dat <- data.frame(col1..some.text = 5:6, col2 = 7:8) 

# find the dataframes that I want to manipulate
dfs <- ls(pattern = ".dat")

# loop through the objects in question, finding and changing the problematic column names
colrename <- lapply(dfs, function(df){
  
  # get the relevant dataframe
  dat <- get(df)
  
  # find its column names
  nms <- names(dat)
  
  # find the column names with the problematic ".." suffixes
  problem.cols <- grep("\\.\\.",nms)
  
  # pull out the meaningful first parts of each problematic name
  parts <- strsplit(nms[problem.cols],"\\.\\.")
  parts <- sapply(parts, function(x) x[1])
  
  # and, the bit that doesn't work: change the problematic column names to their shorter alternatives
  names(get(df))[problem.cols] <<- parts
  return(0)
})
```

If I run this line by line, it does everything I want, up to and including **names(get(df))[problem.cols]**, which it knows are the names of the columns in the dataframe I'm trying to alter. However, it won't assign the altered names to that, yielding the error message: **Error in get(`*tmp*`) : invalid first argument**.

I'm open to alternative approaches to achieve my desired end-point. However, I'm also intrigued by why this doesn't work and how, more generally, it's possible to alter an object referenced using "get()".  Thanks in advance for any advice - and apologies if this is so naive it's been a waste of your time just reading it.

FWIW, I can see the similarity to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261290/error-in-assign-invalid-first-argument) but I can't adapt the answer to my needs.

Comment: Replace get(df) with .GlobalEnv[[df]]. However, this is the result of a bad design. These data.frames should be together in a list instead of in the global environment.

Comment: Thanks @Roland! I take your point about the list (and it had occurred to me that my life would be easier if they were in a list). However, the real dataframes are very different, and also huge. They might also vary in number. I don't want to combine them, if I can avoid it. Thanks for the syntax suggestion though!

Comment: If you actually need get and assign you are doing something wrong or very advanced. A list is just pointers to the actual objects in memory. It needs practically no additional memory but is very convenient if you want to iterate over objects.

Comment: Ah, @Roland, that's reassuring. I guess, therefore, it would be no problem to set up lists temporarily and remove them once finished with. But (at the risk of mission creep) how would I create a list of objects when I don't want to name them individually? Something like (new.list <- list(ls(pattern = ".dat")) but that sets up the pointers, not just a vector of names ... ?

Comment: I think, @Roland, that mget() is the answer I'm looking for - but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.  Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: Yes, mget. But the main point is that you should put such objects into a list when you create them. You shouldn’t even need mget.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I eventually made the link to using the "assign" function.  This seems to work (so I've posted it here, in case it helps anyone else) - but I'd still be interested in alternative solutions:

```
# loop through the objects in question, finding and changing the problematic column names
colrename <- lapply(dfs, function(df){
  
  # get the relevant dataframe
  dat <- get(df)
  
  # find its column names
  nms <- names(dat)
  
  # find the column names with the problematic ".." suffixes
  problem.cols <- grep("\\.\\.",nms)
  
  # pull out the meaningful first parts of each problematic name
  parts <- strsplit(nms[problem.cols],"\\.\\.")
  parts <- sapply(parts, function(x) x[1])
  
  # change the problematic column names to their shorter alternatives
  nms[problem.cols] <- parts
  names(dat) <- nms
  assign(df, dat, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  return(0)
})
```